# How do you find the last occurence of a pattern using string.find?

Tags: string, lua, find

I've been trying to see if I can find the last occurence of a pattern instead of the first using string.fing
For ex. : in string "AAAAABBB" i want to find the position of the last "A" isntead of the first one.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an empty capture:

```
str = "123456AAA7890AAABBBB"
print(str:match(".*()A"))
```

If you need to use `string.find`, try this:

```
local _,p = str:find(".*A")
print(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
local str = "123456AAA7890AAABBBB"
local s, e = str:find("A[^A]*$")

print(s)
print(str:sub(s))
```

Alternatively reverse the string and use a simpler `string.find` call.

```
local str = "123456AAA7890AAABBBB"
local revstr = str:reverse()
local ind = revstr:find("A")

print(#revstr - ind + 1)
print(str:sub(#revstr - ind + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks,
yeah.. the reverse is what I had in mind but given the length of the string I'm working on I wonder how bad the performance hit gonna be.

Comment: I don't see why the "()" in the pattern is needed.

Comment: Oh, it isn't. That was left over from a test.